# Check if column in dataframe is missing values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, frame

I have am column full of state names. 
I know how to iterate down through it, but I don't know what syntax to use to have it check for empty values as it goes. tried "isnull()" but that seems to be the wrong approach. Anyone know a way?

was thinking something like:

```
for state_name in datFrame.state_name:
    if datFrame.state_name.isnull():
        print ('no name value' + other values from row)
    else:
        print(row is good.)

df.head():
 state_name state_ab            city zip_code
0    Alabama       AL       Chickasaw    36611
1    Alabama       AL      Louisville    36048
2    Alabama       AL      Columbiana    35051
3    Alabama       AL         Satsuma    36572
4    Alabama       AL  Dauphin Island    36528


to_dict():
{'state_name': {0: 'Alabama',
  1: 'Alabama',
  2: 'Alabama',
  3: 'Alabama',
  4: 'Alabama'},
 'state_ab': {0: 'AL', 1: 'AL', 2: 'AL', 3: 'AL', 4: 'AL'},
 'city': {0: 'Chickasaw',
  1: 'Louisville',
  2: 'Columbiana',
  3: 'Satsuma',
  4: 'Dauphin Island'},
 'zip_code': {0: '36611', 1: '36048', 2: '35051', 3: '36572', 4: '36528'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you can use `np.where` to check if rows are either `null` or empty strings.

```
df['status'] = np.where(df['state'].eq('') | df['state'].isnull(), 'Not Good', 'Good')
```

(MCVE) For example, suppose you have the following dataframe

```
    state
0   New York
1   Nevada
2   
3   None
4   New Jersey
```

then,

```
    state       status
0   New York    Good
1   Nevada      Good
2               Not Good
3   None        Not Good
4   New Jersey  Good
```

It's always worth mentioning that you should avoid loops whenever possible, because they are way slower than masking